# Resuing same NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray

I am working on an iphone app where I have to pick images from different folder after a button click. I have 5 UIButtons on UI and 5 Images folder each contains near about 100 images. I use same array for all UIButtons images. I fill array by following function :

```
-(void)playAnimations:(NSString*)animationName:(int)photoCount
{

NSString *photoPathName;
UIImage *object = [[UIImage alloc]init];

for (int i=1; i<photoCount+1; i++)
{
    NSString *imagesName=@"";
    if (i<10) {
        imagesName =[photoPathName stringByAppendingFormat:@"000%d",i];
    }
    else if(i>9 && i<100)
        imagesName =[photoPathName stringByAppendingFormat:@"00%d",i];
    else if(i>99 && i<1000)
        imagesName =[photoPathName stringByAppendingFormat:@"0%d",i];

    object = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagesName ofType:@"png"]];//[UIImage imageNamed:imagesName];
    [self.arrayImagesName addObject:object];

}   
self.animationImage.animationImages = self.arrayImagesName;

self.animationImage.animationDuration =durationTime ;// defaults is number of animation images * 1/30th of a second
self.animationImage.animationRepeatCount = 1; // default is 0, which repeats indefinitely
[self.animationImage startAnimating];
}
```

I am getting memory leak again and again from second click(it runs proper on first click) and app gets crashes.

Where I am making mistake? please help/suggest me right way to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem :

```
UIImage *object = [[UIImage alloc]init];
```

you should initialize this `object` variable in the loop,

```
for (int i=1; i<photoCount+1; i++)
{
    // some code
    UIImage *object = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagesName ofType:@"png"]];
    [self.arrayImagesName addObject:object];
}
```

When you press the button, just use your `self.arrayImagesName` array, don't add same image to it.